# Proof monotone convergence theorem, why do they use this lim sup?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have a question about the proof of the MCT. First they use a lemma, this is ok, but I'll show it for completeness:

[image]

Now comes the proof. But I am wondering, why do they use a lim sup here?, why not only a lim?:

[image]

Comment: Using lim requires that the limit exists, whereas limsup exists for any sequence.

Comment: @StefanHansen Thanks, do you see if the proof would have worked with lim inf instead?, or do we need lim sup?

Comment: liminf would have worked as well. All you use is that liminf as well as limsup preserve inequalities.

Comment: @StefanHansen Thanks for the help!